# Select all not disabled input buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, disabled-control

Can I in some way select all input submit elements that are *not* disabled?

I can easily find all the disabled ones with: http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/

```
$("input.saveitembtn:disabled")
```

but is there something a'la:

```
$("input.saveitembtn:NOTdisabled")
```

My solution until now is to run through them all with jQuerys `.each` using `.is` to check each one individually:

```
$("input.saveitembtn").each(function(a){
  if( !$(this).is(':disabled') ) {
    ...
  }
});
```

which I find as total overkill. Is there a simple selector in jQuery?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, there is [**:not()**](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$("input.saveitembtn:not(:disabled)")
```

Answer (score 13):

Not sure why but the accept answer does not work for me.  However this does:

```
$("input.saveitembtn:not([disabled])");
```

Comment: This is could be the reason (from the [jquery-api-doc](https://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/)):  _"Although their resulting selections are usually the same, the `:disabled` selector is subtly different from the `[disabled]` attribute selector; `:disabled` matches elements that are actually disabled while `[disabled]` only checks for the existence of the disabled attribute."_ What the HTML-Standard considers as an "actually disabled" form control can be looked up here: [The disabled attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#concept-fe-disabled)...

Comment: @Mayinx - a few years late here but yes, I'm pretty sure when I posted that I was "disabling" an anchor element, so your explanation is spot on.

Answer (score 2):

Vanilla JavaScript:

```js
const ELS_enabled = document.querySelectorAll("input:not([disabled])");

console.log(ELS_enabled.length); // 2
```

```html
<input type="text" required placeholder="Required">
<input type="text" required disabled placeholder="Required and disabled">
<input type="text" required placeholder="Required">
```